# What are Borderlands' multiplayer game modes?

Tags: borderlands

I have the game and all of its DLC. I am at level 18 in the single-player.

Do you suggest that I finish the single-player before starting **multiplayer**? What are *Borderlands*' multiplayer features/game modes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main Multiplayer mode is co-op.

I would level as co-op from now on. It's very fun (up to 4 players), mobs become more difficult and loot is better.

What is nice about co-op is that each player continues to play in their own story but you all play together (for example 3 people help you on your Quest xy but they already did it).

As far as I can remember, the player's game with the least progression is always the game the other players will also play in.

Comment: "As far as I can remember, the player's game with the least progression is always the game the other players will also play in." Partly true. The host always dictates the missions the party should do. Also, bear in mind that all the enemies will scale up to the host's level (e.g. if the host's level is 50, then the enemies will be something around that level as well).

Comment: The enemies are zone dependent, so that does not really apply. 

But for the missions I agree, let me rephrase. If you want to progress on your own game, you need to host or play with somebody who is not as far as you and who will get your missions shortly.

Comment: I just played this game for the first time with 3 friends and it is absolutely fantastic!

Comment: It seems fun, I definitively have to try, thank you!